# php.ini modified, but unable to upload file

Tags: php

I need to upload a file larger than 2MB. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

So I have modified the two lines on php.ini in this way:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 500M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 500M
```

Then I have restarted apache
In truth, the correct name of the file that I have modified is **php.ini.default** in folder **/etc/**, but I think that the file is correct: in fact if i go on localhost/index.php to show php info, I see:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  /etc
```

However if in terminal; I digit

```
php -i
```

I get this:

```
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
```

It seems like the php.ini file is not been saved, in fact I'm able to upload <=2M but not larger

(sorry for my english )

Comment: have you restarted the server? and if yes check `phpinfo()` and check php.ini location in phpinfo for exact php.ini

Comment: are you working on localhost? then restart your `apache`

Comment: You have to restart apache

Comment: @rahul sorry, I forgot to specify this. Hower yes, in in terminal I have digit `sudo apchectl restart`

Comment: @gulshan yes, I have restarted apache and yes, i'm working on localhost

Comment: `php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'` - did you check this? Because `php.ini.default` seems to be the wrong file.

Comment: check phpinfo and check php.ini file location in there

Comment: maximum post size and set time out as well ... best way to find where you config is changed or not .. go to phpMyadmin and click on import .. after chose file there is the maximum limit for file upload

Comment: `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` should be something like this

Comment: save this file as `php.ini`

Comment: @Tox I checked and I get `Loaded Configuration File => (none)` . Maybe is this my error?

Comment: That seems odd, it should have some configuration loaded. You are on Linux, right? Is it your local machine or a remote server?

Comment: @Rahul i've already checked the location of file. It's in **/etc** directory. If I search `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` I don't find anything

Comment: @Andra if u refer to rename **php.ini.defualt** in **php.ini** I've already tried

Comment: @Tox I'm on localhost on a osx. if it can be of help, have followed this guide to install amps
[link](https://medium.com/better-programming/install-apache-mysql-php-macos-mojave-10-14-b6b5c00b7de)

Comment: Did you try searching your `/etc/` directory for a `php.ini`? Because the path given by Rahul is for the CLI version of PHP 7.4 (which is not released as final yet, so most likely you have a lower version).

Comment: @Tox I have searched `/etc/` for a `php.ini`. In fact here is a `php.ini.default`. Also if I do `phpinfo()` in see this `Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  /etc`. For this, I think that the file is correct. On terminal if I digiti `php --ini`, I get `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`.
During the configuration of AMP, I have modified the http.conf file, in particular this line `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Comment: But renaming the `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` and then restarting `apache2` does not help? I don't know how your setup exactly works, I usually work with **nginx** and **PHP FPM** - in that setup I have to restart **PHP FPM** as well. A simple test could be to reboot your system, that will ensure everything is reloaded. If it works after the reboot, then there is another service that needs to be rebooted for the changes to become active.

Comment: @Tox finally it's work! simply I had to rename the `php.ini.defualt` in `php.ini`. Now if I do
`php --ini`, I have `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini`
I already have done that when I answered @Andra, but probably I'm so stupid because I'm unable to rename a file

Comment: Shit happens, hehe. Good thing it now works :)